# Apple hardware connectivity

Tags: hardware

What licenses are required to connect and communicate over a non-Apple hardware to and from iPad/iPhone?

I have non-apple hardware which I want to connect to iPad and communicate with it by writing a program.

Hence I want to know all steps to be able to do that and how much will it cost.

Comment: Is the non-Apple hardware a device specifically that will connect to the iPad via the dock connector and you will write an app that communicates with it? Or are you just trying to communicate with the iPad from a PC over the standard USB cable.

Comment: I want to connect the device with dock connector or bluetooth to iPAD

Answer (score 1):

You may need to join the [Apple MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/), however this does require you to be a registered company that can pass a credit check.

> **Who should apply to the MFi Program?**
>
> Developers who wish to develop electronic accessories for iPhone, iPad
> or iPod using licensed components and/or software should join the MFi
> Program. Companies, organizations, government entities and educational
> institutions are eligible to apply.
>
> *Case developers, app developers
> and developers of accessories that only use standard technology (e.g.,
> Bluetooth Low Energy or standard Bluetooth profiles) do not need to
> join the MFi Program.*

If you just connect your device via Bluetooth then you do not need to join the MFI program.

All you will need to do in this instance is join the Apple Developer program for iOS devices, the cost for this is $99 a year.

To be able to develop the iOS app to communicate with your device, you will need an Apple Mac capable of running Xcode and costs will vary.